# Apache ignite query stuck

Tags: ignite, gridgain

I try to querying on cached database in apache ignite and i get following log and stuck

**Metrics for local node (to disable set 'metricsLogFrequency' to 0)
    ^-- Node [id=c7f54d16, name=null, uptime=00:01:00:002]
    ^-- H/N/C [hosts=1, nodes=2, CPUs=4]
    ^-- CPU [cur=0.17%, avg=5.01%, GC=0%]
    ^-- Heap [used=851MB, free=53.2%, comm=1031MB]
    ^-- Non heap [used=58MB, free=-1%, comm=59MB]
    ^-- Public thread pool [active=0, idle=6, qSize=0]
    ^-- System thread pool [active=0, idle=16, qSize=0]
    ^-- Outbound messages queue [size=0]**

am i did something wrong?

Query which is not working

```
 SELECT  DISTINCT  m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP FROM (SELECT entry AS a5,QS5.a1 AS a1,QS5.a4 AS a4,QS5.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT entity AS m1,typ AS m1_typ,elem AS a5,QS4.a1 AS a1,QS4.a4 AS a4
 FROM xyz AS T,(SELECT entry AS a2,QS3.a1 AS a1,QS3.a4 AS a4,QS3.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT entry AS a4,QS2.a1 AS a1,QS2.a2 AS a2,QS2.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT entry AS a3,QS1.a1 AS a1,QS1.a2 AS a2,QS1.a4 AS a4,QS1.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT a1 AS a1,COALESCE(S4.elem,val4) AS a4,m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP,COALESCE(S2.elem,val2) AS a2,COALESCE(S3.elem,val3) AS a3
 FROM (SELECT entry AS a1,T.val6 AS VAL4,T.val2 AS m1,T.typ2 AS m1_TYP,T.val8 AS VAL2,T.val6 AS VAL3
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT elem AS a1
 FROM xyz AS T
 WHERE entity = '3' AND typ = 5001 
  AND    (prop = '1oh~#has_neighbours')) AS QS0 WHERE  entry = QS0.a1 
  AND   (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop8 = '1oh~#has_double_bond' AND T.prop6 = '1oh~#has_single_bond' AND T.prop6 = '1oh~#has_single_bond' AND T.prop2 = '1oh~#is_atom_of')
  AND  T.val0 = '7a~') AS Q1 LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S4 ON  Q1.VAL4 = S4.list_id LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S2 ON  Q1.VAL2 = S2.list_id LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S3 ON  Q1.VAL3 = S3.list_id
   WHERE   (  (a1  <>  COALESCE(S4.elem,val4) 
) )) AS QS1 WHERE entry = QS1.a3 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours' AND T.prop8 = '1oh~#has_charge')
  AND  T.val0 = '562~' AND T.val5 = '1' AND T.val8 = '6o7~') AS QS2 WHERE entry = QS2.a4 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '7a~' AND T.val5 = '1') AS QS3 WHERE entry = QS3.a2 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '562~' AND T.val5 = '1') AS QS4 WHERE entity = QS4.m1 AND typ = QS4.m1_TYP 
  AND    (prop = '1oh~#is_atom_of')) AS QS5 WHERE entry = QS5.a5 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '1eg~' AND T.val5 = '0') AS QS6 LIMIT 100
```

Query which works

```
 SELECT  m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP FROM (SELECT entry AS a2,QS3.a1 AS a1,QS3.a4 AS a4,QS3.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT entry AS a3,QS2.a1 AS a1,QS2.a2 AS a2,QS2.a4 AS a4,QS2.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT entry AS a4,QS1.a1 AS a1,QS1.a2 AS a2,QS1.a3 AS a3,QS1.m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT a1 AS a1,m1 AS m1,m1_TYP AS m1_TYP,COALESCE(S3.elem,val3) AS a3,COALESCE(S4.elem,val4) AS a4,COALESCE(S2.elem,val2) AS a2
 FROM (SELECT entry AS a1,T.val2 AS m1,T.typ2 AS m1_TYP,T.val8 AS VAL3,T.val6 AS VAL4,T.val6 AS VAL2
 FROM abc AS T,(SELECT elem AS a1
 FROM xyz AS T
 WHERE entity = '3' AND typ = 5001 
  AND    (prop = '1oh~#has_neighbours')) AS QS0 WHERE  entry = QS0.a1 
  AND   (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop6 = '1oh~#has_single_bond' AND T.prop8 = '1oh~#has_double_bond' AND T.prop6 = '1oh~#has_single_bond' AND T.prop2 = '1oh~#is_atom_of')
  AND  T.val0 = '7a~') AS Q1 LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S3 ON  Q1.VAL3 = S3.list_id LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S4 ON  Q1.VAL4 = S4.list_id LEFT OUTER JOIN efg AS S2 ON  Q1.VAL2 = S2.list_id
   WHERE   (  (a1  <>  COALESCE(S4.elem,val4) 
) )) AS QS1 WHERE entry = QS1.a4 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '7a~' AND T.val5 = '1') AS QS2 WHERE entry = QS2.a3 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '562~' AND T.val5 = '1') AS QS3 WHERE entry = QS3.a2 
  AND    (T.prop0 = '4xm~#type' AND T.prop5 = '1oh~#has_neighbours')
  AND  T.val0 = '562~' AND T.val5 = '1') AS QS4 LIMIT 100
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just the output of current metrics, it's printed out once a minute by default. Why do you think that the query is stuck? Most likely you just didn't properly configure indexes so that it takes a lot of time. Refer to this documentation for details about how to do this: https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/sql-queries

Comment: i had indexes for table which i query and i wait for soo long but didnt get the result so i think its stuck and i follow the above document for that already some of queries are giving result but some is just printing this metric.

Comment: Sounds like it's just takes too long and you need to optimize further. Use `EXPLAIN` to get the execution plan and check if your indexes are actually used.

Comment: thanks valentin but its not work some of my queries work and some are queries are not working, I add 2 queries which are working and not working in question

Comment: i add 2 queries in question on works and other is not so can you once look into it even when i explain query using ggvisorui but its also only show process and not give any plan for query for too long

Comment: `EXPLAIN` has to be fast, you're probably doing something wrong. As for the query, I believe there are scans in the execution plan.